# How can i use multiple url eg. www.example.com,www.example1.com,www.example2.com, to point same project directory?

Tags: web-hosting

I want to use different view along with data for different URL . For example use view1, view1, view2 for www.example.com, www.example1.com and www.site2.example.com respectively.I have managed this making server alias in wamp. How can i do this in real hosting. e.g my registered domain is www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

When you create URLs like "Site1.example.com" or "site2.example.com", you are effectively creating sub-domains on the server. Each sub-domain require separate deployment/installation (unless, you have enabled wildcard setting in sub-domain where all the domains are pointing to single sub-domain/address).

Comment: Thanks for reply.  But i have only one domain name registered,  and want to manage without making subdomain(seperate deployment)

Comment: For sub-domains, you don't have to purchase it, you just need to login to admin panel and create it (your hosting provider can assist you with this.)

Now, since you want "site1/site2", you have to create sub-domains(sorry no other choice.) As you want single deployment for all sub-domains, you have to get wildcard subdomain enabled (hope, your provider supports it) and then write code accordingly.

Your project architect can think over it and can assist you in better decision making